# Pure-CSS-Multiline-Ellipsis Issue with Some Text on Last Line of Content

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to implement the Pure-CSS-Multiline-Ellipsis solution (https://github.com/ericdrowell/Pure-CSS-Multiline-Ellipsis) which uses CSS only to add an ellipsis on text overflow. I've got it working when the text does indeed overflow, but if there is even a few characters on the last line of the content it adds the ellipsis even though no text is overflowing. This happens in FF (v67.0.2 (64-bit)), Chrome (v75.0.3770.80 (Official Build) (64-bit)) & Safari (v12.1.1):

[image: Screen shot]

(Text on the left is properly styled as the text is greater than the container, while the ellipsis shows on the example on the right even though the text ends at "world")

Here's my HTML (edited to show only the problematic div as otherwise the 3000 char limit is exceeded):

```css
/*
 * Pure CSS Multi-line Ellipsis
 */

.ellipsis-container {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.ellipsis-container:before {
  content: "";
  float: left;
  width: 1px;
  height: 100%;
}

.ellipsis-wrapper {
  float: right;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: -1px;
}

.ellipsis-content {
  margin: 0;
}

.ellipsis {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 1px;
  text-align: right;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

@page {
  size: letter landscape;
}

@media print {
  @page {
    size: letter landscape;
  }
}

.printout {
  width: 100%;
  height: 824px;
}

.top_margin_text {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: red;
}

#first_div {
  width: 312px;
  height: 818px;
  float: left;
  padding: 3px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-image: url("https://wonderfest.com/contest/common/img/Copy_Watermark_copy_1_4_NEW copy.png");
  background-position: 75% 45%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.first_div_bckgrnd_color {
  background-color: rgba(192, 192, 192, 0.04);
}

.scissor_left {
  width: 10px;
  height: 818px;
  float: left;
  padding-top: 3px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  padding-left: 33px;
  /*font-family: "Oxygen Mono", monospace;*/
}

.scissor_left img {
  margin-left: -10px;
}

#second_div {
  width: 312px;
  height: 818px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 30px;
  padding: 3px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-image: url("https://wonderfest.com/contest/common/img/Copy_Watermark_copy_2_4_NEW copy.png");
  background-position: 75% 45%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.second_div_bckgrnd_color {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 204, 0.2);
}

.scissor_right {
  width: 10px;
  height: 818px;
  float: left;
  padding-top: 3px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  padding-left: 37px;
  /*font-family: "Oxygen Mono", monospace;*/
}

.scissor_right img {
  margin-left: -10px;
}

#third_div {
  width: 312px;
  height: 818px;
  float: right;
  padding: 3px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-image: url("https://wonderfest.com/contest/common/img/Copy_Watermark_copy_3_4_NEW copy.png");
  background-position: 75% 45%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.third_div_bckgrnd_color {
  background-color: rgba(255, 219, 235, 0.2);
}

.left_logo {
  float: left;
  width: 147px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline;
}

.left_logo p {
  clear: both;
  width: 120px;
  height: 16px;
  color: white;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: thin;
  padding: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-left: 4px;
  font-size: small;
  font-weight: 800;
  background-color: black;
}

.second_logo {
  float: left;
  width: 165px;
  height: 75px;
  display: inline;
}

.second_logo span {
  margin-left: 52px;
  font-size: small;
}

.input-fields {
  clear: both;
  width: 310px;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-left: 3px;
  font-size: small;
  /* This is for the labels  */
  font-weight: bold;
}


/*           .input-fields p{
                    border-radius: 3px;
                    word-wrap: break-word;
                    margin-top: 0px;
                    height: 64px;
                    width: 298px;
                    border: 1px solid black;
                    padding: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
                    font-size: 9pt;
                     font-weight: 300
                    line-height: 1.2em;
                    overflow: hidden;
                }
     */

.ellipsis-container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 3px;
  height: 68px;
  width: 298px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 3px;
  padding: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
}

.ellipsis-content {
  /* it's critical to set a fixed font-size and line-height in order for
                the ellipsis position to be predictable */
  font-size: 9pt;
  line-height: 1.2;
}

.ellipsis {
  /* set width of ellipsis */
  width: 60px;
  margin-left: -60px;
  /* set ellipsis position */
  top: -13px;
  left: 298px;
  /* add a gradient background */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), to(white), color-stop(50%, white));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), white 50%, white);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), white 50%, white);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), white 50%, white);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), white 50%, white);
}

.ellipsis span {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 9pt;
  height: 10px;
  margin-right: 3px;
  line-height: 1.2em;
}

.input-fields input {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding-left: 4px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-size: 9pt;
  /*font-family: "Oxygen Mono", monospace;*/
  font-weight: 400;
  background-color: transparent !important;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.input-fields textArea {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: x-small;
  /*font-family: "Oxygen Mono", monospace;*/
  font-weight: 400;
}

.agreement {
  width: 310px;
  font-size: 5pt;
  text-align: justify;
  margin-left: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}

.accepted_agreement {
  width: 310px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  font-size: 5pt;
  text-align: center;
}

.fold_over {
  width: 310px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: x-small;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.Remarks {
  width: 330px;
  height: 295px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-left: 3px;
  /*font-size:small;
                    font-weight: bold;*/
}

.Remarks p {
  border-radius: 3px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  margin-top: 0px;
  height: 265px;
  width: 298px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 9pt;
  padding: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
  /*font-family: "Oxygen Mono", monospace;*/
  /*font-weight: 400;*/
  white-space: normal;
}

.Remarks textarea {
  width: 300px;
  height: 227px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 9pt;
  /*font-family: "Oxygen Mono", monospace;
                    font-weight: 400;*/
}

.Paid_Watermark {
  background: url("https://wonderfest.com/contest/common/img/WF_Paid_Watermark_sm copy 3.png") no-repeat bottom right;
}

.secure_model {
  width: 310px;
  height: 22px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  font-size: xx-small;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.secure_model input {
  margin-top: 5px;
  /*font-family: "Oxygen Mono", monospace;*/
  font-size: xx-small;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: LightGray !important;
  text-align: center;
}

.barcode {
  width: 310px;
  height: 32px;
  margin-top: 7px;
  font-family: "Libre Barcode 39 Extended", cursive;
  font-size: 24pt;
  text-align: center;
}

.footer_text {
  width: 310px;
  height: 25px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  font-size: small;
}

.first_footer_text {
  width: 75px;
  height: 25px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}

.first_footer_text input {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  /*font-family: "Oxygen Mono", monospace;*/
  font-weight: 500;
}

.middle_footer_text {
  width: 150px;
  height: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: LightGray !important;
  color: black !important;
}

.second_footer_text {
  width: 75px;
  height: 25px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}

.second_footer_text input {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  /*font-family: "Oxygen Mono", monospace;*/
  font-weight: 500;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Libre+Barcode+39+Extended%7CRoboto" rel="stylesheet">


<div id="container">
  <div class="printout">

    <div id="third_div" class="entry_copy third_div_bckgrnd_color">
      <div class="left_logo">
        <img src="" width="138" height="29" alt="logo1">
        <p>Entry Form 2019</p>
      </div>
      <div class="second_logo">
        <img src="" width="168" height="62" alt="logo2">
      </div>
      <div class="input-fields">
        <label>Name:</label><br><input type="text" name="name" value="TEST TESTXXXXXXXXX0XXXXXXXXX0XXXXXXXXX0XXXXXXXXX0XXXXXXXXX0XXXXXXXXX0XXXXXXXXX0XXXXXXXXX0XXXXXXXXX0XXXXXXXXX0XXXXXXXXX0XXXXXXXXX0" readonly>
      </div>

      <div class="input-fields">
        <label>Phone:</label><br><input type="text" name="phone_num" value="5555551212XXXXXXXXX0XXXXXXXXX0XXXXXXXXX0XXXXXXXXX0XXXXXXXXX0XXXXXXXXX0XXXXXXXXX0XXXXXXXXX0XXXXXXXXX0XXXXXXXXX0XXXXXXXXX0XXXXXXXXX0" readonly>
      </div>

      <div class="input-fields">
        <label>Email:</label><br><input type="text" name="email" value="a@b.comXXXXXXXXX0XXXXXXXXX0XXXXXXXXX0XXXXXXXXX0XXXXXXXXX0XXXXXXXXX0XXXXXXXXX0XXXXXXXXX0XXXXXXXXX0XXXXXXXXX0XXXXXXXXX0XXXXXXXXX0" readonly>
      </div>

      <div class="agreement">
        <p> I understand that due to the nature of the model contest, entries are sometimes handled and/or moved because of judging or space management.
          <strong>WonderFest IS NOT</strong> responsible for loss or damage to entries into the model contest. I also grant WonderFest USA, Inc., permission to photograph my model(s) and use such photos in their marketing materials without limitation
          or restriction.
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="accepted_agreement">
        <span>Accepted agreement online: </span>
        <span>15-Jun-19 at 03:08PM EDT</span>
      </div>
      <div class="fold_over">
        <span>Fold Over</span><br><span>- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -</span>
      </div>

      <div class="input-fields">
        <label>Title or name of entry:</label><br>
      </div>
      <div class="ellipsis-container">
        <div class="ellipsis-wrapper">
          <p class="ellipsis-content">
            Call me Ishmael. Some years ago &ndash; never mind how long precisely &ndash; having little or no money in my purse, and nothing particular to interest me on shore, I thought I would sail about a little and see the watery part of the world.
          </p>

        </div>
        <span class="ellipsis" href="#showMore">
                            &hellip;
                          </span>
      </div>

      <div id="Remark3" class="Remarks">
        <label>Remarks:</label>
        <p>fsdfdsfjdsajf fklsdfjsakf jadskfjadskfjdsafj</p>
        <br>
      </div>

      <div class="input-fields">
        <label>Category:</label><br><input type="text" value="Props" readonly>
      </div>

      <div class="secure_model">
        <label>Is model secured to its base? </label><input type="text" size="3" name="secured_to_base" value="Yes" readonly><label style="margin-left:8px;">Oversized entry? </label><input type="text" size="3" name="isOversized" value="No" readonly>
      </div>

      <div class="barcode">
        <span>*2019-1098*</span>
      </div>

      <div class="footer_text">
        <div class="first_footer_text">
          <span>Entry #</span>
          <input type="text" name="entry_num" value="1098" style="width:50px;font-weight:700" readonly>
        </div>
        <div class="middle_footer_text">
          <br><span style="font-size: 8pt">MODELER'S COPY</span>
        </div>
        <div class="second_footer_text">
          <span>Table #</span>
          <input type="text" name="table_num" value="" style="width:50px;" readonly>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The goal is to only show the ellipsis if the text overflows - what am I doing wrong?

My background is in desktop software so I'm just a HTML/CSS hobbyist.

Comment: To make this work here, copied https://github.com/ericdrowell/Pure-CSS-Multiline-Ellipsis/blob/master/ellipsis.css into the style area, and deleted unnecessary (`head`) HTML and set a width declaration to 100% instead of 1000+ pixels. But if you can make a more minimal example (by removing more HTML/CSS), that'd be best. Looks neat, though!

Comment: you can try this library https://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/

Comment: @NitinDaddikar: that JS library removes whole paragraphs, so if the text overflows it removed everything (just showing "...") because I only have 1 paragraph with multiple line breaks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is that the contained text actually *is* taller than the container (by 4 invisible pixels), and so is acting as expected.

Essentially, line-height (and not just the text you see) and any other box padding will expand the contained element. Either increase the container's height a little, or lessen the content's line height a little.

I've modified your layout a little bit to show the issue. The second block is shorter, and no ellipsis. Console.log prints out their actual heights.

```js
$(".ellipsis-container").each(function() {

  console.log( $(this).height(), "vs", $(this).find('.ellipsis-content').height() , "pixels");
});
```

```css
/*
 * Pure CSS Multi-line Ellipsis
 */

.ellipsis-container {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.ellipsis-container:before {
  content: "";
  float: left;
  width: 1px;
  height: 100%;
}

.ellipsis-wrapper {
  float: right;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: -1px;
}

.ellipsis-content {
  margin: 0;
}

.ellipsis {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 1px;
  text-align: right;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

@page {
  size: letter landscape;
}

@media print {
  @page {
    size: letter landscape;
  }
}

.printout {
  width: 100%;
  height: 824px;
}

.top_margin_text {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: red;
}

#first_div {
  width: 312px;
  height: 818px;
  float: left;
  padding: 3px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-image: url("https://wonderfest.com/contest/common/img/Copy_Watermark_copy_1_4_NEW copy.png");
  background-position: 75% 45%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.first_div_bckgrnd_color {
  background-color: rgba(192, 192, 192, 0.04);
}

.scissor_left {
  width: 10px;
  height: 818px;
  float: left;
  padding-top: 3px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  padding-left: 33px;
  /*font-family: "Oxygen Mono", monospace;*/
}

.scissor_left img {
  margin-left: -10px;
}

#second_div {
  width: 312px;
  height: 818px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 30px;
  padding: 3px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-image: url("https://wonderfest.com/contest/common/img/Copy_Watermark_copy_2_4_NEW copy.png");
  background-position: 75% 45%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.second_div_bckgrnd_color {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 204, 0.2);
}

.scissor_right {
  width: 10px;
  height: 818px;
  float: left;
  padding-top: 3px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  padding-left: 37px;
  /*font-family: "Oxygen Mono", monospace;*/
}

.scissor_right img {
  margin-left: -10px;
}

#third_div {
  width: 312px;
  height: 818px;
  float: right;
  padding: 3px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-image: url("https://wonderfest.com/contest/common/img/Copy_Watermark_copy_3_4_NEW copy.png");
  background-position: 75% 45%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.third_div_bckgrnd_color {
  background-color: rgba(255, 219, 235, 0.2);
}

.left_logo {
  float: left;
  width: 147px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline;
}

.left_logo p {
  clear: both;
  width: 120px;
  height: 16px;
  color: white;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: thin;
  padding: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-left: 4px;
  font-size: small;
  font-weight: 800;
  background-color: black;
}

.second_logo {
  float: left;
  width: 165px;
  height: 75px;
  display: inline;
}

.second_logo span {
  margin-left: 52px;
  font-size: small;
}

.input-fields {
  clear: both;
  width: 310px;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-left: 3px;
  font-size: small;
  /* This is for the labels  */
  font-weight: bold;
}


/*           .input-fields p{
                    border-radius: 3px;
                    word-wrap: break-word;
                    margin-top: 0px;
                    height: 64px;
                    width: 298px;
                    border: 1px solid black;
                    padding: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
                    font-size: 9pt;
                     font-weight: 300
                    line-height: 1.2em;
                    overflow: hidden;
                }
     */

.ellipsis-container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 3px;
  height: 68px;
  width: 298px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 3px;
  padding: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
}

.ellipsis-content {
  /* it's critical to set a fixed font-size and line-height in order for
                the ellipsis position to be predictable */
  font-size: 9pt;
  line-height: 1.2;
}

.ellipsis {
  /* set width of ellipsis */
  width: 60px;
  margin-left: -60px;
  /* set ellipsis position */
  top: -13px;
  left: 298px;
  /* add a gradient background */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), to(white), color-stop(50%, white));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), white 50%, white);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), white 50%, white);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), white 50%, white);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), white 50%, white);
}

.ellipsis span {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 9pt;
  height: 10px;
  margin-right: 3px;
  line-height: 1.2em;
}

.input-fields input {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding-left: 4px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-size: 9pt;
  /*font-family: "Oxygen Mono", monospace;*/
  font-weight: 400;
  background-color: transparent !important;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.input-fields textArea {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: x-small;
  /*font-family: "Oxygen Mono", monospace;*/
  font-weight: 400;
}

.agreement {
  width: 310px;
  font-size: 5pt;
  text-align: justify;
  margin-left: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}

.accepted_agreement {
  width: 310px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  font-size: 5pt;
  text-align: center;
}

.fold_over {
  width: 310px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: x-small;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.Remarks {
  width: 330px;
  height: 295px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-left: 3px;
  /*font-size:small;
                    font-weight: bold;*/
}

.Remarks p {
  border-radius: 3px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  margin-top: 0px;
  height: 265px;
  width: 298px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 9pt;
  padding: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
  /*font-family: "Oxygen Mono", monospace;*/
  /*font-weight: 400;*/
  white-space: normal;
}

.Remarks textarea {
  width: 300px;
  height: 227px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 9pt;
  /*font-family: "Oxygen Mono", monospace;
                    font-weight: 400;*/
}

.Paid_Watermark {
  background: url("https://wonderfest.com/contest/common/img/WF_Paid_Watermark_sm copy 3.png") no-repeat bottom right;
}

.secure_model {
  width: 310px;
  height: 22px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  font-size: xx-small;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.secure_model input {
  margin-top: 5px;
  /*font-family: "Oxygen Mono", monospace;*/
  font-size: xx-small;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: LightGray !important;
  text-align: center;
}

.barcode {
  width: 310px;
  height: 32px;
  margin-top: 7px;
  font-family: "Libre Barcode 39 Extended", cursive;
  font-size: 24pt;
  text-align: center;
}

.footer_text {
  width: 310px;
  height: 25px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  font-size: small;
}

.first_footer_text {
  width: 75px;
  height: 25px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}

.first_footer_text input {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  /*font-family: "Oxygen Mono", monospace;*/
  font-weight: 500;
}

.middle_footer_text {
  width: 150px;
  height: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: LightGray !important;
  color: black !important;
}

.second_footer_text {
  width: 75px;
  height: 25px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}

.second_footer_text input {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  /*font-family: "Oxygen Mono", monospace;*/
  font-weight: 500;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Libre+Barcode+39+Extended%7CRoboto" rel="stylesheet">


<div id="container">
  <div class="printout">

    <div id="third_div" class="entry_copy third_div_bckgrnd_color">
      <div class="left_logo">
        <img src="" width="138" height="29" alt="logo1">
        <p>Entry Form 2019</p>
      </div>
      <div class="second_logo">
        <img src="" width="168" height="62" alt="logo2">
      </div>
      <div class="input-fields">
        <label>Name:</label><br><input type="text" name="name" value="TEST TESTXXXXXXXXX0XXXXXXXXX0XXXXXXXXX0XXXXXXXXX0XXXXXXXXX0XXXXXXXXX0XXXXXXXXX0XXXXXXXXX0XXXXXXXXX0XXXXXXXXX0XXXXXXXXX0XXXXXXXXX0" readonly>
      </div>

      <div class="input-fields">
        <label>Phone:</label><br><input type="text" name="phone_num" value="5555551212XXXXXXXXX0XXXXXXXXX0XXXXXXXXX0XXXXXXXXX0XXXXXXXXX0XXXXXXXXX0XXXXXXXXX0XXXXXXXXX0XXXXXXXXX0XXXXXXXXX0XXXXXXXXX0XXXXXXXXX0" readonly>
      </div>

      <div class="input-fields">
        <label>Email:</label><br><input type="text" name="email" value="a@b.comXXXXXXXXX0XXXXXXXXX0XXXXXXXXX0XXXXXXXXX0XXXXXXXXX0XXXXXXXXX0XXXXXXXXX0XXXXXXXXX0XXXXXXXXX0XXXXXXXXX0XXXXXXXXX0XXXXXXXXX0" readonly>
      </div>

      <div class="agreement">
        <p> I understand that due to the nature of the model contest, entries are sometimes handled and/or moved because of judging or space management.
          <strong>WonderFest IS NOT</strong> responsible for loss or damage to entries into the model contest. I also grant WonderFest USA, Inc., permission to photograph my model(s) and use such photos in their marketing materials without limitation
          or restriction.
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="accepted_agreement">
        <span>Accepted agreement online: </span>
        <span>15-Jun-19 at 03:08PM EDT</span>
      </div>
      <div class="fold_over">
        <span>Fold Over</span><br><span>- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -</span>
      </div>

      <div class="input-fields">
        <label>Title or name of entry:</label><br>
      </div>
      <div class="ellipsis-container">
        <div class="ellipsis-wrapper">
          <p class="ellipsis-content">
            Call me Ishmael. Some years ago &ndash; never mind how long precisely &ndash; having little or no money in my purse, and nothing particular to interest me on shore, I thought I would sail about a little and see the watery part of the world.
          </p>

        </div>
        <span class="ellipsis" href="#showMore">
                            &hellip;
                          </span>
      </div>

      <div class="ellipsis-container">
        <div class="ellipsis-wrapper">
          <p class="ellipsis-content">
            Call me Ishmael. Some years ago &ndash; never mind how long precisely &ndash; having little or no money in my purse, and nothing particular to interest me on shore, I thought I would sail about a little [end].
          </p>

        </div>
        <span class="ellipsis" href="#showMore">
                            &hellip;
                          </span>
      </div>

      <div class="input-fields">
        <label>Category:</label><br><input type="text" value="Props" readonly>
      </div>

      <div class="secure_model">
        <label>Is model secured to its base? </label><input type="text" size="3" name="secured_to_base" value="Yes" readonly><label style="margin-left:8px;">Oversized entry? </label><input type="text" size="3" name="isOversized" value="No" readonly>
      </div>

      <div class="barcode">
        <span>*2019-1098*</span>
      </div>

      <div class="footer_text">
        <div class="first_footer_text">
          <span>Entry #</span>
          <input type="text" name="entry_num" value="1098" style="width:50px;font-weight:700" readonly>
        </div>
        <div class="middle_footer_text">
          <br><span style="font-size: 8pt">MODELER'S COPY</span>
        </div>
        <div class="second_footer_text">
          <span>Table #</span>
          <input type="text" name="table_num" value="" style="width:50px;" readonly>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That did it! I just increased the height of the container to 75px and the ellipsis went away. Thanks for the explanation, too - it makes perfect sense now.